# Module Error while lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to lazy load files by reading this [POST](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/).
But not able to implement it. I am getting a 'module error' Error in the firebug.

Here is my project structure:

```
root
|----app
     |----script.js
     |----app.js
     |----appBootstrap.js
     |----login
          |----login.html
          |----login.js
     |----vendor
          |----angular.min.js
          |----angular-route.min.js
|----index.html
```

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body ng-view="">

        <!-- javascript files-->
        <script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/appBootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js code :

```
(function()
{
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $filterProvider, $provide)
        {
            myApp.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
            myApp.compileProvider    = $compileProvider;
            myApp.routeProvider      = $routeProvider;
            myApp.filterProvider     = $filterProvider;
            myApp.provide            = $provide;

            $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'login/login.html', resolve:{ deps: function($q, $rootScope)
            {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                // Add dependencies here
                var dependencies =
                    [
                        'login/login.js'
                    ];

                $script(dependencies, function()
                {
                    // all dependencies have now been loaded by $script.js so resolve the promise
                    $rootScope.$apply(function()
                    {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }}});
        });
})();
```

appBootstrap.js code:

```
$script(['app.js'], function()
{
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
});
```

When I try to load the root folder in the browser, I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…calsearch_new%2Fbranches%2Fb1.0%2Fapp%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A232)
```

Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:** As suggested by @kartikluke added the ngRoute file (angular-route.min.js) but still showing same error but twice now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I followed the link in the error

```
Module Error
error
Description
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
```

`In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.`

<s>Add [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)</s>

Alright so it doesn't seem to be ngRoute.

If you are not sure which module is missing, use the not minified angular.js which gives a readable error message: `"Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/appBootstrap.js"></script>`
```

Alright I looked through your code and I found that after replacing with the unminified code and adding app.js to the scripts I found that the module $compileProvider was not injected.

[image]

`myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $compileProvider)`

Pretty simple in the end. Use the cdn and the unminified code will give you the correct errors.

Comment: tried adding ngRoute file but still giving the same error

Comment: Use the non minified version of Angular it'll give you readable errors.

Comment: sorry not getting any readable errors after using non minified also , error persists

Comment: Try removing the ="" from the ng-view attribute.

Comment: I have uploaded my project folder here  http://www.sendspace.com/file/1xv9k6. Can u please download and check if you dont mind

Comment: Don't have the time right now. Will get to it when I can.

Comment: sure no problem , appreciate your time

Comment: Looks like I found the problem.